# How to create a Python file object representing just a portion of a file

Tags: python, file

I'm using an API that expects me to pass in a file object for reading, but I want to pass in just a portion of an existing file so that the API reads just the first n bytes. I assume I could wrap 'file' in my own class, something like:

```
class FilePortion(file):
    def __init__(self, name, mode, lastByteToRead):
        self.LAST_BYTE = lastByteToRead
        super(FilePortion, self).__init__(name, mode)
    def read(self, size=None):
        position = self.tell()
        if position < self.LAST_BYTE:
            readSize = self.LAST_BYTE - position
            if size and size < readSize:
                readSize = size                
            return super(FilePortion, self).read(readSize)
        else:
            return ''
```

...except I'm not sure what other methods to override and how exactly. How would I override next(), for example? Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: You could Write a generator to do this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/519633/lazy-method-for-reading-big-file-in-python

Answer (score 1):

How about giving it a [`StringIO`](http://docs.python.org/library/stringio.html) object? You can just read the first `n` bytes yourself and place them in the object's buffer.

Comment: I considered this, but I'm dealing with fairly large files and would like to avoid the extra pass of reading memory it would entail.

Comment: A wrapper object is probably your best bet, then. You might just check what calls the API actually uses; you may not need to perfectly implement everything.

Answer (score 1):

You could use existing tarfile._FileInFile wrapper class. Dont make bicycles :)

Comment: +1. It's undocumented, but has been part of Python since v2.5. Or you could just copy it from the [standard library source code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.5/Lib/tarfile.py).